# Is there a limit on the maximum number of threadpools created during an application lifetime?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

Consider the following code:

```java
class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        var t = new Test();
        while(true) {
            t.work();
        }
    }
    public void work() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        try {
             /* Do work */
        }
        finally {
            executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a limit on how many thread pools there can be in the lifetime of the app (not at the same time).

I tried looking into source code and ran this test for some time, but seems like there is no limit. What's going to happen once the thread pool counter overflows?

Comment: There is no explicit limit.

Comment: Note, however, that it takes some time to start/stop threads, so it may be faster to use the same thread pool for all work operations rather than creating a new one for every operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(In Java 11) there isn't a specific limit on the number of thread pools, and there isn't a thread pool counter that might overflow.

There is an ID / sequence number for threads, but since its type is `long` and it is only incremented by one when a new `Thread` is created, overflow is not a practical concern<sup>1</sup>.

However, threads ... and particularly **live** threads<sup>2</sup> ... use a significant amount of memory.  So you can't have an unbounded number of active threads or thread pools in existence at the same time.

---

<sup>1 - Do the math.  How long would it take an application to create 2^63 threads ... assuming there was enough memory, etc.

2 - Threads that have been started, and have not yet terminated.</sup>

Comment: There’s no need to worry about potential thread ID exhaustion anyway, as the implementation is allowed to reuse the ID of a terminated thread. So, only having 2⁶³ nonterminated threads at the same time would exhaust the ID range (which would require *n* × 2⁶³ bytes of runtime memory where the actual value of *n* is irrelevant)…

Comment: That is true.  However, in the current implementation, if you did (hypothetically) manage to get the thread ID to overflow, you could reuse a thread ID for a thread that still existed.  I don't think they check.  (Why would they?)

Comment: I suppose, the ID would first overflow into the negative numbers and we don’t know whether the implementation checks for that. If not, the first violation would be to have negative thread IDs, not to have duplicate IDs. However, I think we agree that an implementation doesn’t need to check, when the scenario is impossible with current computer architectures. But the specification allows to update the implementation when this becomes a concern.

Comment: By the way, there is “a thread pool counter that might overflow”. Its only use seems to be the thread name generation. I just verified it. The 2147483647th thread pool’s first thread has the name `pool-2147483647-thread-1`, the next pool has `pool--2147483648-thread-1`, then `pool--2147483647-thread-1`, etc.

Comment: Oh.  I looked for a counter and couldn't find it.  I'll look again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit. But threads take up their own resources. So it is a matter of how much resources(CPU, memory etc.) are available in the server & how much is allocated to JVM. If the number of threads eat up all the resources, your JVM will crash.